# Would a post-humanity sapient species remember humanity?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse, futurology

Lets imagine a scenario, humanity has disappeared and a new species have come to dominate the world. Would this species have any memories of the concrete jungles or the human infrastructure? Would they even remember humanity at all all? Or would that be lost to pre-history?

Comment: How much of a time gap are we talking between humanity vanishing and the new sapient species?

Comment: Just because a species is the dominant species in their particular ecosystem doesn't necessarily imply that it is sapient, or intelligent. Just that it is very well suited for its environment.

Comment: If they develop telescopes they'll see our space junk, if they develop really good telescopes, they'll see our space junk that's way out in graveyard orbits (junk that far out will be there probably for millions of years). Some mine sites will be pretty obviously not natural for eons.

Comment: I think you need to clean the question up a little bit. Time-frame involved, sapient or not, tech level, etc.

Comment: @Sam there will be technological fossils accessible tens, even hundreds of millions of years hence. Things like house bricks,  dinner plates, the imprints if not the plastic of soft drink bottles.

Comment: @nigel222 True, but a dinner plate is less fanciful that a comms satellite. Even after a hundred million years (can't say which would be in better condition though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Do humans remember the dinosaurs?

Well we don't remember them since they were around before our time.  However, we have done research over the years and have made discoveries over time and gained insight on what they were like.

Depending on how much of a gap between end of humanity and the new species would determine how long before they realize they were not the first intelligent species on their planet.  The time frame would also determine what is still intact from the era of humanity and what they could learn about us.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the meaning of "remember".

AI or post humans might have physical records of humanity from during the transition period between the instantiation of post humanity and the extinction of *Homo Sapiens*, but because they will have different modes of thought (almost by definition) the meaning of these records will be open to interpretation by the post humans. Consider the multitude of interpretation of cave paintings by our very own Ancestors, who are not even a different species, but lived in a very different environment 20,000 years ago.

[image]

*Lascaux Cave Paintings*

Another difficulty is that artificial post humans (strong AI) will have different time scales, subjectively thinking at speeds up to 1,000,000 X faster than biological brains (this is the ratio of speeds between electronic signals inside a computer chip and the electrochemical signals in a mammalian brain). One nanosecond is to one second as one second is to 31.71 years. While we think 20,000 years is an incredible amount of time, for an AI, they could subjectively have that amount of "history" pass in a very short amount of "real" time. Human history will be more remote to them than Homer or the Ancestors are to us.

If we are remembered at all, it may be in creation myths of a flawed race of glacially slow beings who gave rise to the current world.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question with a lot of variables...

In particular, are you talking about simple, oral memories passed down through the generation? If that's the case, it's unlikely - I doubt any species has any understanding of us at present, so if the species descends from a current one then there will be no shared memory. However, *evidence* of humanity will remain for a long time after we're gone - and the more advanced the civilisation, the more they'll notice. Once they're at the stage of archaeology, 21st century human civilisation will yield a bonanza of evidence for them.